# Gstreamer x264enc unexpected LOSS when recording video

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer, h.264, gstreamer-1.0

I recently implement a simple code that can record rtsp stream with changing filesink location dynamically every 10 seconds by referencing [this tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html#changing-elements-in-a-pipeline) and [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Dynamically-updating-filesink-location-at-run-time-on-the-fly-td4660569.html).

Rtsp stream example: [rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov](http://rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov)

However, when I tested an **x264enc** element, the result videos seems to loss lots of frames.

When I open the recorded videos, they start at, for example, 00:07 instead of 00:00.

This is my code....

[test.cpp](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/file/t378587/test.cpp)

Compile:
*g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`*

gstreamer version: 1.14.4

g++ version: 8.2.1

Could anybody help this issue ?

*EDIT:*

I finally solved this problem with the concept :

```
pipeline = rtspsrc ! rtpjpegdepay ! queue ! bin
bin = (ghost pad) ! jpegdec ! openh264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink
```

The `bin` will dynamically remove from pipeline and have a new one added to pipeline every 10 seconds.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you don't want to use the `splitmuxsink` element for that task?

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know this problem can be solved by `splitmuxsink` element !!! Can video names be set by uuid in it ?

Comment: If I put `enc`, `dec` in `bin` (changing dynamically), it will solve my problem. However, I didn't know why it should create a `bin` for dynamically changing `filesink` and its some upstream elements.